# finding r-th root in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: rsa, factoring, number-theory

I was reading the paper *One-way Accumulators: A Decentralized Alternative to Digital Signatures* by Benaloh and de Mare [[link]](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-48285-7_24.pdf), and in section 4.2, they say that given $z\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ and a set
$$\{(z^{1/m_1}, m_1),(z^{1/m_2}),\dots, (z^{1/m_k}, m_k)\}$$ with $m_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, computing $z^{1/r}$ for $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ is hard, which I get since the order of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is unknown.

However, they say that the problem becomes easy if $r \mid m_1m_2\cdots m_k$, and I do not get how it becomes easy.

For the case $k=1$, we have $z, (z^{1/m_1}, m_1) \text{ and } r \mid m_1$, this is easy since $m_1 = k\cdot r$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $(z^{1/m_1})^k = z^{1/r}$

For the case $k=2$, when we have $ m_1 m_2 = k^\prime \cdot r$, we can compute $z^{1/m_1}z^{1/m_2} = z^{(m_1+m_2)/m_1m_2}$ and get $z^{(m_1+m_2)/r}$. However, I do not know how to get rid of the value $m_1+m_2$ to obtain $z^{1/r}$

The case $k>2$ seems even harder.

Any hint on how to move forward will be welcomed

Comment: HINT: [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)

Comment: Would it be better to have the title say "r-th root" in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$? For consistency with the body of your Question.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use extended euclidean algorithm. Here's a numerical example, see if you can figure it out yourself.

Given $z, a := z^{1 / 3}, b := z^{1 / 5}$, we can compute $z^{1 / 15} = a^{-1} \cdot b^2 = z^{-5 / 15 + 6 / 15}$.

Cheers!

Comment: but this only works if for $z^{1/m_1}, z^{1/m_2}$, $m_1$ and $m_2$ are coprime. However, in the paper, they didn't mention something about the gcd of the $m_i$

Comment: @vxek nope, read about extended euclidean algorithm again

Comment: it seems like using extended euclidean algorithm/ Bezout's identity, I can find $z^{1/r}$ if $r = \dfrac{m_1m_2}{\gcd({m_1,m_2})}$
But I am still struggling to see how the $r$-th root is easy if $r$ is a random integer that divides $m_1m_2$

Comment: @vxek Ah, so you are asking how is computing $z^{1 / 24}$ easy when given $z^{1 / 4}$ and $z^{1 / 6}$. Yes, you are correct that it is hard here. The paper assumes that $m_i$ are mutually coprime e.g. when they're all primes. Stop using symbols :)